# Fullstop in a full quoted sentence in the middle of another sentence?

Tags: grammar, quotes, quotations

E.g., The statement made that "Apples are red." is wrong.

Should it be a comma instead e.g., 'The statement made that "Apples are red," is wrong.'?

Comment: "That" is used to introduce an indirect quote, so either the use of quotation marks is incorrect or the use of "that" is incorrect.

Comment: This is not a direct quotation or dialogue,  and the quoted phrase is, syntactically, part of the sentence. Therefore, remove both *that* and all punctuation within the quotes: The statement "apples are red" is wrong.

Comment: @shoryuu If it's a direct quotation, then it needs to be introduced differently: *In his statement to the press, he said, "Apples are red." But he was wrong.* You normally use a comma to *introduce* such a phrase. (Although there other ways of styling and formatting that can bypass that.) But if you preface it with "The statement made that," it is no longer, grammatically, a direct quotation . . .

Comment: But whether it's treated as a direct quotation or not, there would only be a comma after *red* if there would be a comma syntactically: *"Apples are red," he said in a statement that was wrong.*

Answer (score -1):

if the quote is the end of the sentence , then its the finishing side of the quote. if the quote continues, yet not used and the sentence continues or doesn't, it is :- "apples are great...",/.    the full stop CAN be used within quotations if is as in the original, and the base line sentence continues, yet equally, it does not need to be, as rule.